# How to create an image with color gradient in React's JSX?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

This is what I have so far:

```css
homepageImage: {
    position: "relative",
    textAlign: "center",
    height: "100vh",
    backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(
      #3A8DFF,
      #86B9FF
      ), url("images/bg-img.png")`,
  },
```

```html
    <div className={classes.homepageImage}>
```

I got the above code by referencing this Stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370135/section-background-image-and-linear-gradient-not-working), but I guess this method doesn't work with JSX? The colors with the gradient displays in the div, but the image does not appear. I can confirm the url is the correct path as I tested with an `<img>` tag with `"images/bg-img.png"` as the src and the image appears.

Would it be a better approach to create a gradient with the `<img>` tag instead of the `<div>` tag? Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Have a look at this question because it sounds very similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/how-do-i-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradient-on-the-same-element

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Playing around with this:     
backgroundImage: `url("images/bg-img.png"), linear-gradient(#3A8DFF, #86B9FF);` 
Which shows the image now, but no gradient. Will keep trying!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

You need to use **rgba()** to specify the opacity of the color.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>How to create an image with color gradient in React's JSX</h1>
      <div style={homepageImage} />
    </div>
  );
}

const homepageImage = {
  position: 'relative',
  textAlign: 'center',
  height: '100vh',
  backgroundSize: 'cover',
  backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(
      rgba(58, 141, 255, 0.9),
      rgba(134, 185, 255, 0.3)
      ), url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80")`
};
```

Demo : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/image-with-color-gradient-in-reacts-jsx?file=src/App.js)